# NSManagedObject and isDeleted

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a multi-context core data application that uses observers heavily to keep the UI in state.   I'm running into a crop of deletion problems that occur because an observed object is deleted.   I would love to guard my observers with 'if ([mo isDeleted]) return;':

[From NSManagedObject documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003607)

> The method returns YES if Core Data
>   will ask the persistent store to
>   delete the object during the next save
>   operation. It may return NO at other
>   times, particularly after the object
>   has been deleted. The immediacy with
>   which it will stop returning YES
>   depends on where the object is in the
>   process of being deleted.

So ok, terrible design choice in my book, but I'm curious as to how people work around this.   Obviously I need to clear out observed properties prior to deletion.   Only "Clean" way I can think to do this is to observe NSManagedObjectContextWillChange events and see if I am storing any of the deleted objects.   Seems like a clean work around, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another alternative that may or may not work with your design: `-[NSManagedObject managedObjectContext]` will return `nil` if it has been deleted and the context has been saved.  You could check for this after an `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` notification.

Comment: Thanks!  - (BOOL) isReallyDeleted {
 return [self isDeleted] || [self managedObjectContext] == nil;
}